# Subir multiples imagenes desde móvil en un único input type file

Tags: javascript, html

Muy buenas, Tengo el siguiente problema que no puedo solucionar.

Tengo el siguiente formulario html

```
<form action="procesar.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ...
</form>
```

En el cual tengo el siguiente input type file

```
<input type="file" name="images[]" id="images" multiple>
```

Supuestamente este input tiene que dejar cargar varias imágenes para subir, luego recorrer ese array para subirlas hasta el servidor, hsta ahí bien.

Mi problema viene porque esto va a ser usado principalmente en un móvil: Entro en la página, **le doy al input, le doy a hacer foto, pero al realizar la foto termina todo, es decir, solo deja realizar una foto, por lo cual solo carga una en el input.**.

Si por el contrario en vez de seleccionar hacer foto, le doy a cargar imágenes de la galería, si que me deja seleccionar varias fotos, lo cual es el comportamiento correcto, pero necesitaría que funcione también cuando le damos a hacer foto, que hagas, una, luego otra, y así con las que necesite el usuario.

Hay algo que estoy pasando por alto en el input ?

Comment: Creo que es una limitación de la aplicación de la cámara: Si la cámara sólo devuelve un fichero/imagen, en el input sólo se puede añadir ese resultado. Podrías poner varios inputs con el mismo nombre y añadir las imágenes de una en una.

Comment: Para complementar lo que dijo @PabloLozano, puedes poner un evento onchage, y luego con js esconder el input cargado y colocar uno nuevo

Comment: si alguna de las respuestas en tus preguntas solucionan tus dudas, recuerda marcaslas como solucionadas.

Answer (score 1):

No existe algo "Listo para Usar" que solucione tu problema o tu escenario, y la verdad ni PHP ni HTML tienen al menos una forma de llegar a ello.

**Pero... tenemos javascript**
Se me ocurre algo que no es precisamente lo que buscas pero sería la manera a realizar esta hazaña:

1. detectar que estas en un dispositivo movil.
2. permitir que si estas en un dispositivo movil al hacer click en el campo de archivos, invoques directamente a la APLICACION de la cámara y hagas múltiples fotografías.
3. al regresar al formulario detectar el evento y hacer el trigger programático del input type file múltiple, pero abrir directamente la galería de imágenes...
4. seleccionar múltiples imágenes para adjuntar.

Como veras esto es un concepto/solucion basado en las capacidades que sabemos que tiene el entorno movil y el lenguaje javascript. independientemente de HTML y PHP.

Para lograrlo deberas conseguir que cada punto de los mensionado anteriormente funcione.